# Вызов нескольких методов laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть роут

```
Route::get('/historyStorage',[\App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController::class,'getProductListAsSelect'])
```

Можно ли как-нибудь вызвать 2..3..4..5 методов из данного контроллера ?

Comment: кто вам мешает в указанном `getProductListAsSelect` вызывать все нужные вам методы?

Comment: @teran Это было бы слишком просто. Я думал это возможно сделать как то иначе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из коробки только так:

```
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    
    private function method1() {}
    private function method2() {}
    private function method3() {}
    

    public function getProductListAsSelect()
    {
        $this->method1();
        $this->method2();
        $this->method3();
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: методы приватными сделайте